# summing time excel spreadsheet not working

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a issue with excel, I am trying to add up time so they can be displayed correctly in the spreadsheet that I am making, I have requests from user and give them how long it will take to change or fix. on the sheet I am displaying 01:00:00 which means the time taken is 1 hour, and displaying the sum usinfg =sum(A1:A10) which adds up fine when the time is under 24 hours, but if the sum is grater is show up as 03:00:00, i would like to know if it is possible to show time as 27:00:00 which means 27 hours the change will take. not three how would i allow this to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youu need to use the following custom cell format : [hh]:mm:ss

Comment: Hi Roman, this is an answer to his question.  The sum function is probably working fine.  His problem is related to the display format of the cell only.

Comment: Works for me.....@user3086751 - you need to format the **result cell** (the one with your sum formula) with that format. You can also select the option that says `37:30:55` from the time format list